# Table does not stay in one page

Tags: tables, tabularx

Good morning.

I have used the tabularx package to make a table. However, when I put it into my code, the table is half in a page and half in another one, notwithstanding the fact that it is quite small.

I understand that I can wrap it into a table environment:_however, aesthetically speaking, it becomes quite ugly (spacing is not the same as in tabularx).

EDIT:
Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
           % tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,
            lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[english]{babel,subcaption,cleveref}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{mytabularwrap}{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}
  {\end{lrbox}%
  \setbox0\hbox{\usebox\mybox}%
  \ifdim\wd0<\textwidth
      \usebox\mybox%
  \else
      \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
  \fi
  }

\title{...}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\section{Section A}

\subsection{Subsection A.A}
\lipsum[1-2]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.  Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.  Nam arcu libero,nonummy  eget,  consectetuer  id,  vulputate  a,  magna.   




\begin{center}
\small
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {14cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \caption{Frequencies}\\
\toprule
\textbf{}&No.&Freq.&Cum. \\
\midrule
0-5&1279&87.2&87.2 \\
5-10 p.&156&10.6&97.8 \\
15-20 p.&30&2.0&99.9 \\
20-25 & 0 & 0.0 & 99.9 \\
25-30 &2&0.1&100.0 \\
\hline
\textbf{Total}&1467&100.0& \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\normalsize
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

What I get is something like:

[image: break]

and you could see that the table gets from one page to the other.

Comment: You can surround it by a `minipage` to make it stay on one page.

Comment: I support @Skillmon. But using a table environment should not be a problem.

Comment: `tabularx` could not be split over two pages. For this you need special packages as `ltablex` etc. Apparently in your case something else is going on. To help you, we need MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete/compilable document) which will demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added some clarifications.

Comment: As already mentioned: `tabularx` cannot have a pagebreak! This is the reason why you must load some other packages, e.g. `ltablex` which redefines `tabularx`. Using `xltabular` instead makes more sense.

Comment: Please convert your code fragment to complete small document which we can compile as it is. Your fragment not reproduce your problem (now is not clear, what it is).

Comment: Off-topic: why you define 16 columns and than use only four?

Comment: Here there is an example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zfgjhqqrggrw

user187802 the fact is that I do not wanto it to make a pagebreak.

Zarko: I am using a package in Stata which automatically creates tables in Latex, that is why it defines 16 columns

Comment: Please post a minimal example *here*. People will not usually follow external links in order to understand your question, which should be self-contained.

Comment: I posted the code here. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placement of table is consequence of use `ltablex` package. It is combination `tabularx` and `longtable` package. Consequently it enable to break tables between packages. If you not like this, you need to encapsulate your table into float `table` environment (the best solution) or in `minipage`.

Use of `ltablex` also reformat `X` column. If its contents are shorter than their natural width, it will be accommodate to contents width. Instead it I would rather use `xltabular` which is also combination of `tabularx` and `longtable` packages (without changed column types behavior).

I would for your table rather use simple  `tabular` environment and `S` column types for columns with numbers:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
           % tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,
            lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}    % cause your problem
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}  % new
\usepackage{siunitx}            % new
\usepackage{hyperref}   % had to be load last
%\usepackage{url}       % loaded by hyperref

\title{...}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Section A}

\subsection{Subsection A.A}
\lipsum[1-2]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,nonummy  eget, consectetuer  id, vulputate a, magna.
    \begin{table}[ht]   
    \centering
\caption{Frequencies}
\begin{tabular}{l   S[table-format=4.0]
                    S[table-format=2.1] 
                    S[table-format=3.1]
                }
    \toprule
            & {No.} & {Freq.}   & {Cum.}    \\
    \midrule
 0-5        & 1279  & 87.2      &  87.2     \\
 5-10 p.    & 156   & 10.6      &  97.8     \\
15-20 p.    &  30   &  2.0      &  99.9     \\
20-25       &   0   &  0.0      &  99.9     \\
25-30       &   2   &  0.1      & 100.0     \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Total}
            & 1467  & 100.0 &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]